# Blended Bandwidth with multiple carriers How to configure IP address

Tags: networking, ip, internet, bandwidth, ip-address

I have seen many colocation companies offering something called "Blended Bandwidth" and that makes me wonder how do they do it?

Here is my example. If I would get two internet services, from ISP-A and ISP-B. They both would give me IP addresses to use on their own network. If one would fail, I would not be able to use the IPs from ISP-A on the connection of ISP-B.

I know, to use simply private addresses behind a router... But that is not how they do it.

So any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll Answer my own question in case if someone comes across this problem.
To be able to swap IP addresses between ISPs, you'll need to buy a block of Public IP. In case of IPV4 at least /24 block. This can be done on IP Address auctions or through brokers. Approx 6000 USD for a /24 block. Once you have them completed the paperwork to "Own" the addresses you'll have to get an AS# and start to advertise that on your router with BGP through all your connections.

Comment: You don't need to acquire your own addresses, if one of the ISPs you're working with is willing to let you announce the block they've given you through another ISP as well.